# C# Stopwatch - Returning inconsistent values

Tags: c#, debugging, time, stopwatch, diagnostics

There may be a duplicate but I didn't know how to explain my problem.

I'm running performance timing of the Floyd Rivest Algorithm I implemented (on different cases) using the .NET Stopwatch.

To better understand the problem, here is the code.

I am executing the 3 following methods one after the other:

> analysis.FRStopwatch(analysis.getOrderedArray());
>   analysis.FRStopwatch(analysis.getDescendingOrderedArray());
>   analysis.FRStopwatch(analysis.getUnorderedArray());

The method FRStopwatch(int[]) does the following:

```
public double FRStopwatch(int[] array)
{
    frs = new FloydRivestSelection(array);
    double avg = 0;
    Stopwatch s = new Stopwatch();
    for (int i = 0; i < k.Length; i++)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(10);
        s.Start();
        frs.Select(k[i]);
        s.Stop();
        avg = avg + (double)s.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds;
        s.Reset();
        Console.WriteLine(avg);
    }
    avg = avg / (double)k.Length;
    return avg;
}
```

The output I get is the following:
[Original Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JP76e.png)

As one can see, the ordered array's timing is way larger than the others.

Then I commented out the first line shown:

> analysis.FRStopwatch(analysis.getOrderedArray());

and executed only the remaining two in the following order:

> analysis.FRStopwatch(analysis.getDescendingOrderedArray());
>   analysis.FRStopwatch(analysis.getUnorderedArray());

I got the following output: 
[New Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/awNFN.png)
It seems like the first method that uses the Stopwatch is working incorrectly (or the other two are working incorrectly?). How do I fix is so that the results are consistent? Does the problem have to do with my computer (CPU ticks etc)?

Comment: If `frs.Select(k[i]);` takes less than a few milliseconds, this will be a really horrible way to time it.

Comment: @Kim Few keywords: cache, JIT and possibly object state. Far to be complete and perfect (you still need to use it cum grano salis, Eric Lippert wrote a nice entry-level post about benchmarking) but you may want to give a try to this [microbenchmark utility](https://github.com/arepetti/NetMicroBenchmark) (disclaimer: I wrote it)

Comment: The initial delay could be due to JIT - try timing the whole thing twice in a loop.

Comment: JIT was the problem here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A single sample of a small request is subject to too many variables.

To get a better indication of performance, run each a few thousand times (say 6000), then discard the first 1000 or so results to get rid of any warmup factors (JIT / caching etc).

Take your results and divide by 5000 to get an average execution time. this approach will help you keep your sanity and give a better indication of performance.

Comment: After learning that it's a JIT problem I found a way to get around this using Environment.TickCount.

Comment: @KimScicluna how Environment.TickCount will help you about JIT compiler? Reducing timer accuracy?

Comment: Scratch that. As you suggested, just running the method once before the testing begins did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Those lines are problematic:

```
avg = avg + (double)s.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds;
Console.WriteLine(avg);
```

You are increasing the average, but you output the sum. Try this instead to output the "current" average.

```
avg = avg + (double)s.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds;
Console.WriteLine(avg / (i+1));
```

Or this, if you are interested in the runtimes of every single iteration:

```
Console.WriteLine(s.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);
//reset after instead of before of course
s.Reset();
```

Comment: No, it's just a poorly named variable.  If you look after the loop there is an `avg = avg / (double)k.Length;` statement, computing the average.  The inner variable should have been named `sum`.

Comment: @DStanley Exactly. It's **after** the loop. The return value is correct, the Console output isn't

Answer (score 0):

You are printing to the console the accumulative sum of the times, not the average nor the individual times.

I suggest that you print the individual times like this:

```
s.Start();
frs.Select(k[i]);
s.Stop();
var elapsed = (double)s.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds;
avg = avg + elapsed; //it is really sum, not avg
s.Reset();
Console.WriteLine(elapsed);
```

I guess that the fist iteration for the first method will consume the largest amount of time probably because of [JIT compilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation). If you print individual times, you will see this clearly.

Also, I suggest you change the variable name from `avg` to `sum`, and only calculate the average after the loop.